# JSON values are not returning

Tags: android, json

I have array of values displaying in the KeyValue pair as JSON format. I'm using JSON Object to get the values and displaying in app. I'm checking the type and keyvalueStatus from JSON. I'm getting the type is image or video. But the keyvalueStatus always showing 0. Below keyvalueStatus is 1 but in app i'm getting 0 and the phonenoButtonName, websiteurlButtonName, websiteurl etc returning empty values nothing coming.

```
{
    "type":"image",
    "link":"http:\/\/once.com\/images\/eWFD5ahswOO6X2.jpg",
    "keyvalueStatus":1,
    "phonenoButtonName":"Call",
    "phoneno":"6526268",
    "websiteurlButtonName":"JDO",
    "websiteurl":"once.com",
    "facebookurlButtonName":"fb",
    "facebookurl":"https:\/\/www.facebook.com\/",
    "latestofferurlButtonName":"Offer",
    "latestofferurl":"kart.com"
}
```

Activity.java:

```
String type="", link="", overlayurl="",phonenoButtonName="" ,websiteurlButtonName="",websiteurl="",facebookurlButtonName="",
            facebookur="",latestofferurlButtonName="",  latestofferurl="";

    int keyvalueStatus, phoneno;

String json = result.getMetaData();
                JSONObject j = new JSONObject();


                try{
                j= new JSONObject(json);
                type = j.getString("type");
                link = j.getString("link");


                keyvalueStatus=j.getInt("keyvalueStatus");



                phonenoButtonName = j.getString("phonenoButtonName");
                phoneno=j.getInt("phoneno");

                websiteurlButtonName = j.getString("websiteurlButtonName");
                websiteurl = j.getString("websiteurl");

                facebookurlButtonName = j.getString("facebookurlButtonName");
                facebookur = j.getString("facebookur");

                latestofferurlButtonName = j.getString("latestofferurlButtonName");
                latestofferurl = j.getString("latestofferurl");

                }catch(Exception e){

                }

                if(t == 0){
                    t = 1;
                    inflateImageLayout();
                }




                if(type.equalsIgnoreCase("image")){



                    if(keyvalueStatus==0){

                        // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Overlay url is"+ keyvalueStatus, 
                                  // Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                        doStopTrackers();
                        //doDeinitTrackers();

                         LoaderImageView ldr = (LoaderImageView) findViewById(R.id.loaderImageView);
                         findViewById(R.id.videoView1).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                         findViewById(R.id.loaderImageView).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                         findViewById(R.id.button1).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                         ldr.setImageDrawable(link);

                         findViewById(R.id.websiteurl_btn).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                         findViewById(R.id.facebookur_btn).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                         findViewById(R.id.latestofferurl_btn).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                         findViewById(R.id.phoneno_btn).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                          Log.d(link,LOGTAG1);

                    }else{

                         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Overlay url is"+ phoneno, 
                                   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Overlay url is"+ keyvalueStatus, 
                             //  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Overlay url is"+ phonenoButtonName, 
                                 //  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        doStopTrackers();
                        //doDeinitTrackers();

                         LoaderImageView ldr = (LoaderImageView) findViewById(R.id.loaderImageView);
                         findViewById(R.id.videoView1).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                         findViewById(R.id.loaderImageView).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                         findViewById(R.id.button1).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                         ldr.setImageDrawable(link);


                         findViewById(R.id.websiteurl_btn).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                         findViewById(R.id.facebookur_btn).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                         findViewById(R.id.latestofferurl_btn).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                         findViewById(R.id.phoneno_btn).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);


                          Log.d(link,LOGTAG1);

                    }




                     // image.setImageDrawable(link);



                }
```

Comment: put `log.d("myTag", e.getMessage())` in catch block to check any exception has occurred.

Comment: try replacing `getString()` to `optString()` and `getInt()` to `optInt()`

Comment: I dont see any logCat output, I'm guessing that you dont see it too. Just add e.printStackTrace(); to your catch method. Maybe your result.getMetaData() is empty?

Post your logCat output so I can help you!

Comment: I'm getting type & link values.. But other values are not coming

Comment: @rajraj Before try block write `log.d("myTag", json)` and in catch block write `log.d("myTag", e.getMessage())`. Then run your program and post logcat.

Comment: @rajraj change `j.getString("facebookur")` to `j.getString("facebookurl")`. Check for other possible mistakes.

Comment: First of all you should log your jsonObject so that you are 100% sure that there is no 0 value inside. You can do it by Log.d("json",j.toString()); Then post the result here